# Why does this JS function not work on load?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am currently working on my website ([pastebin](https://pastebin.com/CcJda8TD) in case I forgot to remove my E-Mail, don't worry; it's my public address). When I call the function `showTab()` from any of my navigation bar buttons to change the background of the active tab, it works without any problems. However, when I try calling the function for my "Home" tab on page load like this:
 `showTab(0)`
 or like this:
 `document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() { showTab(0) }, false);`
It does not work. I first have to click on my "Home" button (or any of the other buttons) for the function to work (`for (let i = 0; i < tabButtons.length; i++) {tabButtons[i].addEventListener('click', function() { showTab(i) }, false)}`).

I've also tried calling the function in different locations just to be sure but nothing worked thus far.

Here is my function:

```js
function showTab(panelIndex) {
  {
    tabButtons.forEach (function(node) {
      node.style.backgroundColor = ''
      node.style.color = ''
    })
    tabButtons[panelIndex].style.backgroundColor = 'rgb(66, 66, 66)'
    tabButtons[panelIndex].style.color = '#ffffff'
  }
}
```

`var tabButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.tabContainer .buttonContainer button')`
My HTML looks like this:

```html
<div class="tabContainer">
  <div class="buttonContainer">
    <button>Home</button>
    <button>Projects</button>
    <button>Contact</button>
    <button>Bio</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Does `document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() { console.log("ready"); }, false);` output to the console?

Comment: `tabButtons` was not defined ..

Comment: @obscure No, it doesn't...

Comment: @MisterJojo Yes it was.

Comment: @MP0 even if you refresh the browser (hit the reload button)?

Comment: how ? _ (i don't see it there) => you didn't show us all needed information...

Comment: You have to call `showTab(0)` in the context of the `initialize` function, after `tabButtons` has been initialized.

Comment: @MisterJojo My pastebin. `var tabButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.tabContainer .buttonContainer button')`

Comment: this is not the point : is this definition happened before your calling on `showTab(0)` => this is a real information!

Comment: So, that's what I said ... (tabButtons **was** not defined) ... and you certainly had an error message in the debugger, but you did not bother to look at it before posting this question.

Comment: + node.style.color = '' is invalid ...

Comment: @MP0 Solutions do not go in the question body.  They go in the answer field.

Answer (score 0):

A far better approach is to apply styling to an "active" class and apply that class to the button that was clicked. This is better because it separates the styling and function to their own respective areas (css versus js) which gives a cleaner code structure.

Note that the active class is aplied to the home button - this could be altered on the other pages so that each page has its own button set as the active one.

Also - this seems like its a nav structure - and should therefore be be a `ul` inside a `<nav>` element, IMO.

```js
document.querySelector('.buttonContainer').addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  var el = event.target;
  
  if(el.getAttribute('type') == 'button'){
    var id = el.getAttribute('id');
    setActiveButton(id)
   }
   
});


function setActiveButton(id) {
  document.querySelectorAll('.buttonContainer button').forEach(function(button) {
    button.classList.remove('active');
  })
  document.querySelector('#' + id).classList.add('active');
}
```

```css
button {
  background: #ffffff;
  color: rgb(66,66,66);
}

button.active {
  background: rgb(66,66,66);
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="tabContainer">
  <div class="buttonContainer">
    <button id="home-button" type="button" class="active">Home</button>
    <button id="projects-button" type="button">Projects</button>
    <button id="contact-button" type="button">Contact</button>
    <button id="bio-button" type="button">Bio</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you made a bad space on first  `color: rgb (66,66,66);` => `color: rgb(66,66,66);`

Comment: In this case the better is to use event delegation, not  4 event listener..

Comment: @MisterJojo - thanks for suggestions - edits made to my solution. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

"same" solution, with event delegation.

```js
window.onload = _=>{
  const tabButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.tabContainer .buttonContainer button');

  document.querySelector('.tabContainer .buttonContainer').onclick = e=>{
    if (!e.target.matches('button')) return;
    e.stopPropagation();
    tabButtons.forEach(bt=>{bt.classList.remove('active')})
    e.target.classList.add('active')
  }
}
```

```css
button {
  background: none;
  color:transparent;
}
button.active {
  background: #424242;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="tabContainer">
  <div class="buttonContainer">
    <button class="active">Home</button>
    <button>Projects</button>
    <button>Contact</button>
    <button>Bio</button>
  </div>
</div>
```